# How to resolve these unresolved imports in PyDev ( eclipse )?

Tags: python, module, ubuntu-12.04

I get unresolved imports for these,

```
from gi.repository import GLib, GObject, Gio
from gi.repository import Dee
from gi.repository import Unity
```

I've been learning to write lens for unity(ubuntu). Where/How to get these modules and link them?

Answer (score 2):

Are those in your PYTHONPATH? Have you tried adding 'gi' to the forced builtins? See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project node and choose `Properties`. Choose `PyDev - PYTHONPATH` and the `External Libraries` tab. Press `Add source folder` and add the directory above the one that contains your `gi` package. That is, if you have `/src/gi/repository` you should add `/src`.

Comment: And where is the `gi` package source located in a typical Ubuntu install?